# derive seed with derive path HD wallet

Tags: python, cryptocurrency

I'm trying to write a python script that converts bip39 HD passphrases to keys.

the steps I have found from a nodejs code snippet are:

1. mnemonic to seed
2. derivedseed from derivepath
3. keypair from RawEd25519Seed

I've done (1) with phrase_to_seed from bip39

I'm stuck on #2 because I can't find an obvious command/function in any modules. The derivepath is m/44'/314159'/0'

any ideas about this?

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Consider making a [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the section [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking another question.